# How to add diffent makers on the image

Tags: media, theming

How to add a marker in different part of the image (please look at the attached photo),

[image]
There is a module Imagefield marker which is not working. is there any other similar module?

Thank for the help.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/image_annotator

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/image_hotspots

Answer (score 0):

[ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) is the right module which you're looking for. Enable `Imagecache Actions` and `Image Effects Text` module

Go and edit the image style at admin/config/media/image-styles and select effect `Text`. 
[image]